# XCB get all monitors ands their x, y coordinates

Tags: xcb

So far I have got all monitors. A monitor is a screen. So what I did was:

```
xcb_connection_t *conn;

conn = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);

if (xcb_connection_has_error(conn)) {
  printf("Error opening display.\n");
  exit(1);
}

const xcb_setup_t* setup;
xcb_screen_t* screen;

setup = xcb_get_setup(conn);
screen = xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;
printf("Screen dimensions: %d, %d\n", screen->width_in_pixels, screen->height_in_pixels);
```

This gives me the width and height. However it is critical that I get the x and y. Is doing `xcb_get_window_attributes_cookie_t` on the `screen->root` the way to get the x and y?

I was reading here - http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/3/xcb_get_window_attributes_unchecked.htm - but there were no x/y coords given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that you are interested in the geometries of monitors, i.e., actual physical devices, and not of the X screen.

In that case, the root window isn't what you are interested in. There are basically two different things to consider here:

- The old legacy [Xinerama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) extension.
- The newer [RandR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RandR) extension.

To learn how to query all kinds of details, my recommendation would be to look at programs that do this. A canonical suggestion would be a window manager that supports multi-head setups, such as the i3 window manager which, in fact, supports both Xinerama and RandR, so you can look at its source code for both.

The information you are looking for can be found in `src/randr.c` and `src/xinerama.c`. The necessary RandR API calls are

- `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current`
- `xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs`
- `xcb_randr_get_output_info`
- `xcb_randr_get_crtc_info`

The latter of those will give you the CRTC information of an output which includes the position and size of the output.

Another source for the RandR implementation would be [xedgewarp:src/randr.c](https://github.com/Airblader/xedgewarp/blob/master/src/randr.c)*. I'll include a heavily shortened excerpt from that source code here:

```
xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply_t *reply = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_reply(
        connection, xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current(connection, root), NULL);

xcb_timestamp_t timestamp = reply->config_timestamp;
int len = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs_length(reply);
xcb_randr_output_t *randr_outputs = xcb_randr_get_screen_resources_current_outputs(reply);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    xcb_randr_get_output_info_reply_t *output = xcb_randr_get_output_info_reply(
            connection, xcb_randr_get_output_info(connection, randr_outputs[i], timestamp), NULL);
    if (output == NULL)
        continue;

    if (output->crtc == XCB_NONE || output->connection == XCB_RANDR_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED)
        continue;

    xcb_randr_get_crtc_info_reply_t *crtc = xcb_randr_get_crtc_info_reply(connection,
            xcb_randr_get_crtc_info(connection, output->crtc, timestamp), NULL);
    fprintf(stderr, "x = %d | y = %d | w = %d | h = %d\n",
            crtc->x, crtc->y, crtc->width, crtc->height);
    FREE(crtc);
    FREE(output);
}

FREE(reply);
```

*) Disclaimer: I am the author of that tool.

**Edit:** Note that you also need to listen for screen change events and then query the outputs again if you are interested in keeping your information up to date.

Comment: Oh wow thank you! This is how I was currently doing it, I was using Xrandr from a thread but I hear its not thread safe, so i wanted to switch everything to xcb. This will help me tons than you so much! https://github.com/Noitidart/NativeShot/blob/master/modules/screenshot/ScreenshotWorker.js#L1505-L1530 the docs on this xcb stuff i couldnt find, thanks very very much for it!!

Comment: Yeah, xcb is not well documented in a lot of areas, unfortunately. Most of the time it's perfectly fine to look at the docs for the Xlib equivalent, transferring the information to xcb is usually trivial. Glad I could help!

Comment: @IngoBürk Does RandR work with NVIDIA and AMD proprietary drivers these days? ("The manufacturers of the most popular and widespread closed source drivers, nVidia and AMD/ATI, refuse to support RandR. Instead, they prefer to offer their own RandR-incompatible solutions.") http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2009/106/Multi-heading-with-RandR

Comment: Yeah, RandR is the de-facto standard.